# Eclipse updates not working

Tags: eclipse, networking, update-site

I have installed Eclipse 3,6 on 64 bit Windows platform. 
When I try to connect to update sites by going to `Help->install new software` it gives following error:

```
Unable to connect to repository 
http://download.eclipse.org/releases/galileo/content.xml
Connection refused: connect
```

I have tried all available sites - they all give me the same error.
Dialog box shows: `Provision exception`.

Any idea what's happening?

Comment: Are you able to access the URL using a browser?

Comment: Maybe some kind of temporary issue like in http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&goto=502111& ?

Answer (score 17):

1. In Eclipse (go to Window > Preferences > General > Network connections).
2. Select "Active Provider" as "Manual".
3. Select HTTP and click edit.
4. Enter the  host and port
5. Select "Requires Authentication" and enter the username and password.
6. Repeat Step 1 to 5 for Https.
7. In "proxy bypass" section click "Add host"
8. Enter http://download.eclipse.org/releases/galileo/content.xml and OK

After spending an entire week with the issue, this solution finally worked for me

Comment: thank you! (Grumble, grumble, why doesn't Eclipse just use the system proxy settings? And why does it let you specify a proxy which is just ignored until you locate the obscure "Active Provider" drop down?)

Comment: You can select `Direct` at `Active Provider` and Nothing to do any other steps. Its working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're behind a firewall, and need to access the web through a proxy. Have you set a proxy in your web browser? If so, you need to set the same proxy in Eclipse (go to Preferences > General > Network connections).

Comment: I did not set up any proxy for my web browser.

Answer (score 0):

Well, try to enter this website: http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.6.x

If that link works, then it's not your fault. I've tried your link, and it doesn't work for me either.

If the link I gave you doesn't work either, then the problem is on your side and you need to check your network settings.

Comment: I tried that link from eclipse update site.. same error is thrown:

Answer (score 0):

If you are behind a firewall, have set the proxy settings in the preferences correctly and it's still not working, Try setting `-Dsun.net.client.defaultReadTimeout=<"amount in ms, e.g. 30000">` in the eclipse.ini worked well for me. It looks like Eclipse has a quick timeout on that updatesite search. Some proxys can slow the process down by a few seconds and you get a timeout before the updatesite is loaded completely