# Eclipse Indigo "unable to connect to repository"

Tags: eclipse, repository

I'm trying to add this repository to Eclipse (Indigo):-

http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo

Seems okay when checked in a browser, but I keep getting "unable to connect" in Eclipse, and when I check the URL Eclipse is apparently looking for:-

http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo/content.xml

in a browser, I get a "404 not found". The locations for previous releases (e.g. galileo) don't seem to be there either. Have they moved? Am I misunderstanding something?

I tried some of the suggestions in this previous thread:-

[Eclipse updates not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598167/eclipse-updates-not-working)

But they don't seem to work (and I'm not using a proxy anyway).

- Hemdoar

Comment: Did you try closing your eclipse, deleting `<eclipse>/p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository/cache` and relaunching your eclipse, adding the repo again?

Comment: I couldn't find that exact folder. I found a similar cache folder, and cleared that, but it made no difference.

Comment: Ok. It was worth a try. All the other informations I have found are about the presence of a proxy, which isn't your case.

Comment: No problem, and thanks for the suggestion. You're right that it made sense to try- while searching this, I'd come across some other similar problems that had to do with a proxy. FWIW, progress update: I tried the installation on an XP machine at work, and it seemed to go okay, so I'm trying that at home. Strange...

Comment: The URL should already be included, have a look at `Help > Install Software > Already Installed Software`. See my answer on [Unable to read repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7625943/unable-to-read-repository-at-http-download-eclipse-org-releases-indigo/7626392#7626392)

Comment: has anyone figured this out yet? I don't get why people keep suggesting to do stuff in eclipse. he says right in the question that he can't even open it in an external browser. If I can't get to it from an external browser, then what good would it do me to change eclipse settings?

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me:

Open terminal. Navigate to Eclipse folder.

```
sudo nano eclipse.ini
```

at the bottom, add this line in:

```
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack = true
```

Then ctrl+O to save, ctrl+X to close (it says at bottom). IPv4/IPv6 problems? Solved.
Then delete the cache VonC said to:

```
<eclipse>/p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository/cache
```

(This can be done using "sudo rmdir /p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository/cache" or by typing "sudo nautilus" into terminal, to open a root-priveleged filesystem browser, than navigating to, selecting the folder, and pressing the delete key). Then restart eclipse, goto Help>install new software>available software sites

Make sure the repos you want (such as "http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates/") has a "/" right at the end. If it doesn't, delete that entry, and create a new, identical one which does, because Eclipse won't just let you edit it and click ok. Then click ok, and from the combo box choose e.g. the egit link, and lo, it will find it.

Still not working? Window>show view>internal web browser; check it can access internet. Hope that helps!

Credit to:
[http://drfits.com/2011/11/13/eclipse-contacting-software-sites-has-encountered-a-problem/](http://web.archive.org/web/20120831112227/http://drfits.com/2011/11/13/eclipse-contacting-software-sites-has-encountered-a-problem)
VonC Sep 14 '11 at 6:03

Answer (score 2):

I used VonC's answer to good effect. I also uninstalled a program called webroot. I think this had something to do with it because other programs were also having network problems.

Answer (score 1):

This is because windows IPV6 issue. Try adding the following VM option in the eclipse.ini

```
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you connect to internet at all through Eclipse?

Open the internal webbrowser. In Eclipse: Window -> show view -> Other -> General: Internal web browser.
Look up any normal adress, is it working?
Can you connect to another update site? Try for example Eclipse Emma: http://update.eclemma.org/ Do you see anything there?

What are your proxy preferences? Go to Window -> preferences -> General: Network connections.

The active provider:

Specifies the settings profile to be used when opening connections. Choosing the Direct provider causes all the connections to be opened without the use of a proxy server. Selecting Manual causes settings defined in Eclipse to be used. On some platforms there is also a Native provider available, selecting this one causes settings that were discovered in the OS to be used.

If internet is working fine outside of Eclipse, try changing to Native. After that, try Direct.

I have encountered problems where an update site would not load, then I had to remove it and add it again. This forces Eclipse to reread the contents of the site even if it has a cached copy. So, if you still get no connection to the indigo update site, but everything else is working, try that. Go to Window -> Preferences -> Install/update: Available Software sites. Then remove and add the indigo site. Just remember to copy the adress so you can add it again.

As suggested in a comment below by @lostiniceland, this is a simpler way to achieve the above:

Goto Preferences -> Install Update -> Available Software Sites => select the entry and click the "Reload" button to the right. This is sometimes also helpful when you have a local updatesite for testing custom plugins

Answer (score 1):

first **resolve proxy conflicts** and if then too eclipse is not getting connected to internet **turnoff your firewall/antiviru**s and try again

To resolve proxy conflicts:Go to windows->prefernces-general tab->network settings

1. if you dont use proxy settings, cgange native to direct
2. if you use proxy, chenge native to manual and fill details of proxy for http and https by pressing 'edit' and clear SOCKS tab by pressing 'clear'

check if your SOCK is disabled on operating system too. or doing it open to 'Internet options' dailog box. Go to connections and press lan connection. press 'advanced' button ans clear the textboxes in front of 'socks' and uncheck the msg saying 'use same address for other network protocols'

I did this and worked for me

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Fiddler2 (or any other web sniffer/debugger tool), it may be your problem, as it acts as a local proxy.

Sometimes, even if its not running, I find myself obligated to start it and disable traffic capture.

Hope that helps!