# Installation of EPIC within eclipse juno

Tags: eclipse, macos, perl, epic

I'm installing EPIC within eclipse but always get an error:

```
Unable to read repository at http://e-p-i-c.sf.net/updates/testing/content.xml
```

I tried the second answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7409691/eclipse-indigo-unable-to-connect-to-repository) which is:

1) add the line in eclipse.ini: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack = true

2) delete eclipse/p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository/cache directory

But still get the error. However I can install CDT correctly.

I'm using Mac OX Lion and Eclipse Classic 4.2.1 the mac os 64bit version. I also tried to switch to 32bit version but didn't work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Just encountered this same problem, hope we find an answer :)

Comment: My guess is this is the same as: http://sourceforge.net/projects/e-p-i-c/forums/forum/258687/topic/5424638?message=11660363 -- when I installed epic in the past, I think the problem was that the link is no longer maintained and you have to install it manually

Comment: @vol7ron Maybe we should try install it manually...

Comment: I just tried and wasn't successful.  I forget what I did to get it to work on my Ubuntu installation.  I guess it serves me right for setting up Emacs first

Comment: please respond to my answer. thanks

Comment: Your repository should be: http://e-p-i-c.sf.net/updates OR, http://e-p-i-c.sf.net/updates/testing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the site from your "Available Software Sites".
1) Go to "Help" > "Install New Software" > "Available Software Sites"

Find the URL you mentioned in the list and delete it.

Note: Then install EPIC from marketplace if required.

Comment: Yes,I've fixed it. Actually I did nothing. The last try happened a few weeks after I asked this question and it just went ok. I think maybe there is something wrong with the website http://e-p-i-c.sf.net/updates/testing/content.xml previously and they fixed it when I tried the last time and then it is successfully installed.

Comment: That URL gives me a 404. I suspect the URL is old and needs to be replaced with a current EPIC update URL, e.g. from the marketplace.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to install EPIC in Eclipse:

**Way One:**

1. Open Eclipse
2. Go to Help -> Install New Software and click Add button
3. Enter Name as EPIC and Location as follows:
   http://e-p-i-c.sf.net/updates (for the stable 0.5.x, older version of EPIC)
   http://e-p-i-c.sf.net/updates/testing (for the most recent 0.6.x version)
4. Follow the instruction of eclipse pop up
5. After successful installation go to Window -> Preferences and observe the list as "Perl EPIC" at 
   left side panel

**Way Two:**

1. Open Eclipse
2. Go to Help -> Eclipse Marketplace
3. Type EPIC at Find text box and click Go button
4. Click Install button at "EPIC - Eclipse Perl Integration" area
5. Follow the instruction of eclipse pop up
6. After successful installation go to Window -> Preferences and observe the list as "Perl EPIC" at
   left side panel

Answer (score 1):

This is another posible answer, besides the ones already provided.

I just hit this, and it was a firewall rule the issue.
In fact the file `content.xml` doesn't exist on the plugin update (it has instead a `site.xml`) but that is what the error says when it cannot reach outside world

Solution would be to just open ports 80 and 443 to Eclipse

PS: this happened to me while installing a new version of Eclipse which was not whitelisted in the firewall rules