# Eclipse does not connect to any update site but internal browser does work

Tags: eclipse, connection

I tried to configure Network Connections but it did not work.

Eclipse's Internal Browser opens all update sites normally.
In IE and Firefox trere are no proxy configuration, but sometimes they request my windows username and password before browse a page. Perhaps there is a transparent proxy, I don't know.

The error:

```
Unable to connect to repository http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo/content.xml
Unable to connect to repository http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo/content.xml
Connection timed out: connect
```

Answer (score -1):

Those links 404 meaning the other end is having problems

Edit - I was wrong, apparently this is an ongoing [issue](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/270718/)

One potential fix is to set

```
-vmargs -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

in your eclipse startup.

Comment: This is also asked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7409691/eclipse-indigo-unable-to-connect-to-repository