# Cannot download Weblogic server adapter in RAD 7.5

Tags: eclipse, adapter, rad, weblogic-10.x

I need to configure Weblogic 10g server with my RAD 7.5. When I try to download the Oracle Weblogic server plugin using `Server -> New Server -> Download additional server adapters...`

I am getting this error:

```
Could not connect to update.eclipse.com, download.oracle.com, etc.....
```

Please help to configure weblogic server with RAD.

Comment: It seems to be a network-related problem. Did you check your networking settings or firewall policy? Can you download any other server adapter?

Comment: Yes... I tried other servers as well but nothing is working. Where to check the network settings.? from IE i am able to access all the sites. Also from eclipse Internal web Browser i am able to access all the sites. please help.

Comment: No i am not behind any proxy.

Comment: Its working now....!!!!! problem with the proxy setting I changed my proxy configuration its works.. thanks u......!!!

Comment: I created an answer which tries to sum up your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most cases it's because of the networking problems (**firewall** or **proxy** settings). Try checking your firewall policy and check if you're not behind any proxy (or if it's appropriately configured in the Eclipse).

**Useful resources:**
-  [Eclipse can't update ?](http://www.daemonforums.org/showthread.php?t=2325) 
-  [Eclipse updates not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598167/eclipse-updates-not-working)